# Using try-catch to skip exception causes falling into an infinite loop

Tags: java, exception, httpurlconnection, connection-timeout

I have this difficulty that for some URLs, the `BufferedReader` reaches a `Connection timeout` and throws an exception which interrupts the whole program. What I need is to either check the time that a connection is spending for opening and if it reaches a threshold, which must be less than of the one for timeout, it skips that URL to open a stream and then fetch the next URL or it handles a timeout in a way that does not cause the program to stop. Is there any idea how to do such?

```
URL url = new URL(line);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
if (connection instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
int statusCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
if (statusCode <= 200 && statusCode < 300)
  try{                 
   BufferedReader brURL = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));    
   while((tempLine = brURL.readLine())!=null){                          
   UrlMatcher=UrlPattern.matcher(tempLine);
   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SimpleCrawler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, tempLine);
           if(UrlMatcher.find())
            {
                String resultURL=UrlMatcher.group();
                fop.write(resultURL.toLowerCase().getBytes());
                fop.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());

               System.out.println(resultURL);
          }


                                            }                
  }
                           catch(ConnectException ex){}

             }
```

Causing this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
    at simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler.main(SimpleCrawler.java:61)
```

**EDIT** Using try-catch, now it falls into an infinite loop in some other part of execution.

**EDIT 2**

By adding a `logger` before `if(UrlMatcher.find())`, inside the while-loop, when it goes to the infinite loop, it shows the following log (I include the last match before the log for further clarity)

```
 rum-static.pingdom.net/prum.min.js //the last match
SEVERE: var flashvars = {};
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: flashvars.enableAPI = "true";
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: flashvars.galleryURL = "/svgallerysource.asp?galleryid=685";
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: var params = {};
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: params.bgcolor = "222222";
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: params.allowfullscreen = false;
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: params.wmode = "transparent";
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: var attributes = {};
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: attributes.id =  "svInstance";
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: attributes.name = "svInstance";
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: simpleviewer.ready(function () {
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: simpleviewer.load('flashContent', '920', '420', '222222', true, flashvars, params, attributes, true); 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: }); 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: </script>
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: <link href="http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: <style type="text/css">
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE:      #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE:  </style>
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: <script type="text/javascript" src="/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: <script type="text/javascript" src="/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.inspector.js"></script>
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/colorbox.css" />
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: <script>
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: var _prum = [['id', '5397955dabe53dbb3ea78d70'],
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE:              ['mark', 'firstbyte', (new Date()).getTime()]];
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: (function() {
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE:     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE:       , p = document.createElement('script');
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE:     p.async = 'async';
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE:     p.src = '//rum-static.pingdom.net/prum.min.js';
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE:     s.parentNode.insertBefore(p, s);
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: })();
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: </script>
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: <style>
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE:     
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: body
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: {
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: background-color: #ffffff;
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: }
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: div#bodycontainer-home
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: {
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: background-color: 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: #ffffff; 
Nov 27, 2015 6:53:27 PM simplecrawler.SimpleCrawler openConnection
SEVERE: background-image:url(/images/uploaded/540973958472458.png);
```

Comment: Why don't you just catch the exception?

Comment: @VinceEmigh you mean using try catch?

Comment: Yes, catch the `ConnectionException`. If a runtime expetion is thrown, it won't crash the thread if you catch it

Comment: @VinceEmigh how to catch it then? I mean, what would be in the catch section in this case?

Comment: Seems as if someone already wrote an answer, feel free to tag me in a comment if it doesnt work for you

Comment: @VinceEmigh or should it be just `catch(ConnectException ex) {}`?

Comment: @VinceEmigh ok, it seems that `catch(ConnectException ex){}` works just fine and thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Yes, since a `ConnectException` is being thrown, that's the exception you would wanna catch

Comment: @VinceEmigh ok, but now, for some other URL, the thread waits infinitely and does nothing. I edited my code to what I am using now, maybe I used try-catch in a wrong way?

Comment: It won't 'wait infinitely'. The connect attempt will timeout after a minute, or less if you set a connection timeout. Note that you can't *increase* the connect timeout beyond the default.

Comment: @EJP but right now, it does wait infinitely. using this try-catch it passes previous point that my program stops but now, in some other moment for some other URL it waits infinitely. I waited for 7 min and the program did nothing.

Comment: However it might *loop* infinitely if you are ignoring the `ConnectException` inside a loop.

Comment: @VinceEmigh can you take a look at the current problem? now it falls into an infinite loops, some other point of execution.

Comment: The words I used were 'improperly indented, illegible mess', and you've done nothing about it. Merely using a try/catch doesn't excuse all other faults.

Comment: @EJP I guess you are missing the point. You asked to add the actual code in the while-loop and I did. Where is not so clear?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setConnectTimeout` and then *catch* `SocketTimeoutException`.

```
try { 
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
 con.setConnectTimeout(5000); //set timeout to 5 seconds 
return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK); 
} 
catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) { return false; }
```

See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int)) here.

Comment: It says `change the return type to Boolean`

Comment: So do that, or change `return false` to whatever you need on a connect timeout.

Comment: @EJP If I change it to Boolean, then the main thread has to be a Boolean type which is not possible.

Comment: @EJP In addition, I already mentioned that what I want on a connection time out, just to skip the URL and fetch the next one from the brURL. and I must say that his answer did not work at all, it still throw the exception and interrupts the thread. However, the code above in my question passes that point but then, i will be trapped into an infinite loop which I dont know why.

Comment: If you call e.getMessage() in your catch block, the program will perform the catch and move on the next URL since you are reading lines (read URLs) using while loop, which continues execution as long as it encounters Null value in the Url.

Comment: @KunalChawla still infinite loop at a certain part of execution.

Comment: So change `return false;` to `continue;`, or whatever is required for you to progress to the next URL. You haven't posted that part of the code and it is unreasonable to expect other people to guess at what may be required.

Comment: @EJP I clearly posted the part of code and then you called it a mess. you jsut randomly say something while this is not possible to replace `return false` with `continue` whatsoever.

Comment: I must tell everyone that I am not using this answer cause this answer solves nothing. When I am saying it has an infinite loop, it is referring to my own code.

Comment: Could you please use Logger to see what is happening in that infinite loop so that we can solve your problem in a better way ? :)

Comment: @KunalChawla what to?

Comment: @seventeen - you're saying that your program falls into infinite loop in some part of the execution. I want to know where exactly that is happening so that the error can be rectified.

Comment: I meant, how to use a logger?

Comment: This should help - www.vogella.com/tutorials/Logging/article.html

Comment: do you mean something like :
`java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SimpleCrawler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, tempLine);
`

Comment: So I see, You do not know nothing.

Comment: Yup. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.